# Laravel and vuejs app not showing pages in browser

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, vue.js, amazon-ec2, vue-router

I have a Laravel and Vuejs app working perfectly on my local machine, when i deployed it to an EC2 instance running ubuntu on amazon, the app is not loading the vue components on the browser. The only thing showing is the preloader in welcome.blade.php

Nothing else is showing. i checked all logs; laravel.log, nginx error logs and there is no error in any of the log files

Comment: Did you create a build and copy the public folder to your EC2 instance? If you check your network tab in devtools, can you see the .js file being loaded properly?

Comment: Did you compile your assets? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix

Comment: i have done all your suggestions and now am seeing the following errors in browser console  : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <,
Uncaught ReferenceError: i18n is not defined,
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: I have tried installing jquery with npm, autoload jquery in webpack but still those errors are still showing in the console and the page remains blank